# Express: Show value from external request as response

Tags: node.js, rest, express, callback

I have the following function where I am using the cryptocompare npm package:

```
getPrice: function(coin){
  cc.price(coin, 'USD')
  .then(prices => {
    console.log(prices);
    return prices;
  }).catch(console.error)
}
// https://github.com/markusdanek/crypto-api/blob/master/server/helper/cryptocompare.js
```

Now I want to set up an Express server to open http://localhost:9000/current and to display the current "price".

So I have my controller which looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    getCurrentPrice: function(req, res, next) {
      getPrice('ETH', function(price);
    }
};
// https://github.com/markusdanek/crypto-api/blob/master/server/controllers/CryptoController.jshttps://github.com/markusdanek/crypto-api/blob/master/server/controllers/CryptoController.js
```

My route:

```
var controllers = require('../controllers'),
    app = require('express').Router();

    module.exports = function(app) {
        app.get('/current', controllers.crypto.getCurrentPrice);
    };
```

When I open now http://localhost:9000/current I only get the current price in my console, but not in my browser.

How can I also set the response to the value?

I tried this but failed:

```
module.exports = {
    getCurrentPrice: function(req, res, next) {
      getPrice('ETH', function(price){
        res.status(200).json(price);
      });
    } 
};
```

I guess thats the wrong way to call a callback.. do I have to modify my helper function or anything else?

My project is also on Github for further references: https://github.com/markusdanek/crypto-api

Comment: welcome again @mrks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below may help you

```
module.exports = {
    getCurrentPrice: function(req, res, next) {
      cc.price('ETH', 'USD')
        .then(prices => {
          console.log(prices);
            res.json(prices)
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.error(err)
            return next(err);
        })
    }
};
```

Comment: go through http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html first. may it help to design MVC pattern